# Pass function value to hidden field in form

Tags: javascript, forms

How can I pass `txt = txt + "\n" + x.options[i].value;` to a hidden field in a form? Below my code:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type=button class="master" name=b1 id=b1 value='Move >'>
    <input type=button class="master" name=b2 id=b2 value='< Remove'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name=category[] id=category multiple="multiple" class=master>

        <?php   
        $file = fopen("category.csv", "r");
        while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $category = $row[0];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category;?>"><?php echo $category;?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="master" id="master" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Save File" onclick="displayResult()" name="submit" >
</form>
```

And here my updated JS.

```
<script>
    function displayResult() {
    var options = document.getElementById('master').options;

    var values = [];
    var i = 0, len = options.length;

    while (i < len)
    {
      values.push(options[i++].value);
    }

    txt=(values.join(','));
        alert(txt);
        document.getElementById('masterlist').value = txt;
        }
    </script>
```

It now works 100%. The `value = txt` is transferred to my form hidden field correctly and on form submit `action="update.php"` values are written to my  master.csv & category.csv files respectively. Herewith my update.php file

```
<?php
header("Location:".$URL.'index.php');

if ($_POST['masterlist']) {
$list = $_POST['masterlist'];
$str_master = explode (",", $list);
foreach ($str_master as $key => $value) {
    $resultmaster.=$value. "\n";
}
file_put_contents('master.csv',$resultmaster);
}

if ($_POST['category']) {
$category = $_POST['category'];
$categoryunique = array_unique($category);
sort($categoryunique);
foreach ($categoryunique as $key => $value) {
    $resultcategory.=$value. "\n";
}
file_put_contents('category.csv',$resultcategory);
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried after the alert allocating the value of the txt inside the hidden input with `document.getElementById("master").value ==  txt;` ? or with the `innerHTML` variation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the value of txt in your javascript function like this:

```
document.getElementById('master').value = txt;
```

Then the value should be set to your hidden field.

Comment: I had 2 id=master so I have changed the id=masterlist in hidden form field. and add `document.getElementById('masterlist').value == txt;`

If I submit my form it writes empty value
`if ($_POST['masterlist']) {
$master = $_POST['masterlist'];
foreach ($master as $key => $value) {
    $result.=$value. "\n";
}
file_put_contents('master.csv',$result);
}`

When I dump var I get this
`array(3) { ["masterlist"]=> string(0) "" ["category"]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(5) "April" [1]=> string(8) "February" [2]=> string(7) "January" [3]=> string(4) "June" } ["submit"]=> string(9) "Save File" }`

Comment: But actual you are not assign the value of txt to the value of the element, because you use 2 of == you have to type: 'document.getElementById('masterlist').value = txt'

Comment: wonder how to go about if I add another 10 categories. Is it possible to make one function? How do I trigger function and how do I retrieve values
`<input type="hidden" name="master1" id="master1" value=""> <input type="submit" value="Save File" onclick="displayResult()" name="submit" > <input type="hidden" name="master2" id="master2" value=""> <input type="submit" value="Save File" onclick="displayResult()" name="submit" > <input type="hidden" name="master3" id="master3" value=""> <input type="submit" value="Save File" onclick="displayResult()" name="submit" >`  ...etc